# python requests returns different status codes locally/production

Tags: python, django, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

all.
trying to access a foo.com using python requests library from the django application.

i'm using same versions of all dependencies locally and in production. django application is hosted on elastic beanstalk.
locally requests to foo.com returns status code 200 . while production request to the same page is always 403 . 
also , production requests to bar.com returns 200 . 
there is nothing in the aws EB logs.

where should i look for clues for this issue?

python3. requests 2.20.1.

****//**** 
production request/response  403
****//****

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0'}

{'Date': 'Tue, 19 Mar 2019 21:22:49 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': 'BIGipServer~blpart~prod_cag_int_pl=1729895340.36895.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure, TS0146ef81=018311fb76135815ac1df572d8f2d1ea5aa4467189900a3c4bd271f978754ddcfc965e0f553f77c07b7d60700425d031c96db5abf8ed876c1f62e240755ba80603a146246f; Path=/', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

****//****
local request/response  200
****//****

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0'}

{'Date': 'Tue, 19 Mar 2019 21:21:42 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '164', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': ‘foo’, 'Transaction-Guid': '32f6c127-065c-48ae-90b5-360e41a6fe68', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Application-Context': 'application:PROD,dc2-pod-bootstrap:8015'}

Comment: Please consider rephrasing the title of your question to be more informative and searchable. Take a minuter to read [How to as](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55249775/edit) your queston. Also, make sure your question contains a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise people will have a hard time reproducing your problem.

Comment: Since accessing the URL to foo.com does not time out but yields a 403 forbidden error, this seems to be on the end of foo.com. Perhaps they block the IP range? Maybe try a setting a different User Agent in the request - not that I think will it solve the problem...

Comment: I suggest you save the body of the response with 403 and check it out. Sometimes, the host will explain exactly why it's giving you 403.

Comment: @phoibos ip range blocking is highly probable thing at this point

Comment: 10 different ip ranges got same result